# different packages version sets based on environment in node

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I need to install different packages version sets based on deployment environment in node app.

this must be the dependencies when the env = develop

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
 }
```

and this must be the dependencies when the env = production

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.2.0",
 }
```

Do you have some workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use penv module. it allows to create environment file and you will be able to separate out dependencies based on environment.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/penv

There is another way to create multiple package json files. e.g. DEV.package.json, QA.package.json and main.package.json. you can merge them using npm module during your CI Process.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json-merge